# Create new graph and delete the old graph with Python

Tags: python

I have code for graph clustering using the Louvain algorithm.  In the second phase I must create a new graph from the old graph, so a node in the new graph represents a cluster of nodes in the first phase. Here is my code:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.name=n
        self.description=str
        self.maxV1=int
        self.maxV2=int
        self.neighbors=list()

        def add_neighbor(self,v):
        if v not in self.neighbors:
            self.neighbors.append(v)
           #self.neighbors.sort()

class Graph:
    verticies={}

    def add_vertex(self,vertex):

        if isinstance(vertex,Vertex) and vertex.name not in self.verticies:

            self.verticies[vertex.name]=vertex
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def add_edge(self,u,v):
        if u in self.verticies and v in self.verticies:
            for key, value in self.verticies.items():
               if key==u:
                  value.add_neighbor(v)
               if key ==v:
                  value.add_neighbor(u)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The problem is when creating a new instance of class `Graph` and adding nodes and edges, they will be added with the old graph. I want to add the new nodes in a new graph.